# What would you call a contraption that uses a string or a cord to turn on a light?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

When I was younger, I hated to fumble my way in the dark to my bed, so I rigged up a string that ran from my light switch, across the ceiling and down to my bed. I could tug on it to turn off the light when I was ready.

What would you call this type of contraption?

Comment: I'd call it a cord.

Comment: It's called a [pull cord or pull chain](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Pull-Chain-Socket-Lamp-Holder-R50-19980-0PG/100357007).  If it's extended then it's an [extension](https://www.lookupbubbles.com/Product/395732/spare-pullcord-switch-string-and-acorn-for-bathroom-ceiling-light-fittings-x-2) (sometimes simply called a *pull*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what silly things you may have done to route the string over to your bed, it would almost qualify as [Rube Goldberg Contraption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)

> A Rube Goldberg machine is a contraption, invention, device or
>   apparatus that is deliberately over-engineered to perform a simple
>   task in a complicated fashion, generally including a chain reaction.
>   The expression is named after American cartoonist and inventor Rube
>   Goldberg (1883–1970).

Another phrase for such things might be a "j[ury-rigged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_rigging) solution"

> Jury rigging refers to makeshift repairs or temporary contrivances,
>   made with only the tools and materials that happen to be on hand,
>   originally a nautical term. On sailing ships, a jury rig is a
>   replacement mast and yards (which hold the ship's rigging) improvised
>   in case of damage or loss of the original mast.

In north american pop culture, you might also be said to have "McGuyvered" the problem, which stems from a TV character who always managed to solve complex problems with simple materials at hand in a make-shift fashion. "Oh look - an atomic bomb...well let me disarm that with a stick of gum, two staples, and a sandal!"

Comment: I pounded nails into the ceiling and then looped the string loosely around them. Pretty sure my parents were not happy with that! :)

Comment: lol, no doubt! But still, to my mind a real Rube Goldberg is something insanely silly - like the breakfast-making machinery at the start of Chitty Chitty Bang Bang if you are familiar with that movie (starts at about 1:45 here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBJGpNTP_lY if you aren't).

Answer (score 3):

I've always known the non-Heath Robinson version as a **lazy betty**.

Though I haven't found a dictionary reference, This article from [Sue's Considered Trifles](https://suesconsideredtrifles.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/name-game/) concurs:

> A lazy Betty is a pull-cord light switch, which may be operated from a
>   bed.

In answer to the obvious follow-on question '**Why** is the light switch above beds called a *lazy betty*? Who was Betty?'
the only comment I've been able to find sadly says 'No record for "lazy betty" '

But [a critical review of *Brooks, Philips V.; “Kitchen Utensils names, origins and definitions through the ages”; Palgrave MacMillan, New-York; 2004*](https://yvesforges.wordpress.com/2014/07/05/brooks-philips-v-kitchen-utensils-names-origins-and-definitions-through-the-ages-palgrave-macmillan-new-york-2004/) does mention a probable partial etymology:

> **The lazy susan**
>
> I then went to the entry [in the work by PV Brooks] for the *lazy
>   susan* which appears on page 76 under the name lazy-back, idle back.
>   He gives the following definition :
>
> [A bent iron or other metal open frame attached to a pot or kettle to
>   prevent burning hands when removing such from a fire.
>
> AKA: kettle tilter, lazy susan, lazy Betty, tipper, lazy elbow. Cited
>   in Feild.]
>
> Now Feild says that kettles would be hung from them so that they could
>   be tipped and poured without taking them off the fire” (page 97, ill.
>   nº 72). She never mentions that they would be used to remove them from
>   the fire.
>
> These implements were not and could not be an aid to remove the kettle
>   from the fire. Their design prohibits such a use. Brooks did not read
>   Feild well and he seems to have limited his research to Feild.

Comment: This is interesting, Betty who?

Comment: I want to know who  Betty was!

Comment: I haven't. But I'm researching trails in Capitol Reef NM at the moment.

Comment: What's the 'Heath Robinson' version?

Comment: In the US, a lazy susan is a rotating tray with various compartments containing ingredients, such as the toppings for tacos.  If the cheese is facing the other side of the table, you rotate the lazy susan to get the cheese on your side...assuming you want cheese in the first place. http://www.legendcookshop.co.uk/images/detailed/17/lazy-susan.jpg

Comment: ... It is in the UK too. The earlier usage, not this, is relevant.

Comment: A Heath Robinson version is, for instance, one where you 'rigged up a string that ran from [your] light switch, across the ceiling and down to [your] bed'. The ones in our house have ceiling-mounted switches trailing cords.

Answer (score 2):

When I was a young guy around 1960 I fitted many Lazy Betties, it is an actual devise you could buy at most electrical shops. It was a brown Bakelite switch similar in shape and size to a hens egg operated by a slide through push button either side, similar in operation to a reading lamp switch. It was suspended from the ceiling, above the bed by its electrical supply cable, at a convenient height so you could just reach up without siting up. Far simpler, more convenient and reliable than anything we use to switch the bedroom lights off or on in modern times.

Comment: I remember those too but I would call them a pendant light switches. The difference is (as you know since you fitted them) that there has to be wiring in the ceiling running from the wall switch to a point over the bed. As an alternative you could have fitted cord pull ceiling switches which are much safer. The really good thing about the cord pull switches is that they can be 2-way whereas any pendant switch I have ever seen has been 1-way and has to be switched on again before the wall switch can be used next time. The OPs device required no wiring, just a cord.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you added was an  ***[extension](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extension)***:

> a something that can be extended or that extends another object.

(Collins)